# Problema con la conexión a la base de datos pgadmin

Tags: pgadmin

Tengo un problema con la conexión a la base de datos, hasta ayer todo funcionaba perfectamente pero ahora cuando intento conectarme desde pgadmin me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is
>   the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost"
>   (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

He hecho prácticamente todo lo que se comenta en foros como por ejemplo intentar iniciar el servicio desde PANEL DE CONTROL / HERRAMIENTAS ADMINISTRATIVAS / SERVICIOS, pero con nada de lo que he probado me ha llegado a funcionar.

Estoy utilizando pgadmin 4. Estaré muy agradecido de cualquier ayuda que podais ofrecer.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos!

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema. He seguido los pasos indicados y continuo igual... Hay otra alternativa?

Comment: Lo pudiste resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Debes revisar si está corriendo el servicio con el usuario, si estas con Windows debes hacer los siguientes pasos:

PANEL DE CONTROL
HERRAMIENTAS ADMINISTRATIVAS
SERVICIOS

Busca PostgreSQL Server x.x o postgresql-x.x"
Abre el servicio y en la ficha INICIAR SESSION, cliKclea donde dice INICIAR SESSION COMO y elige CUENTA DEL SISTEMA LOCAL, le das en aplicar y reinicias el servicio en la pestaña GENERAL

Comment: Buenas Eduardo, muchas gracias por responder ante todo. Eso que dices es lo que comento arriba que es lo que he visto que le soluciona el problema a la mayoria de la gente que se encuentra con este problema. Al realizarlo seguía sin funcionarme y despues de reinstalar pgadmin varias veces ahora mismo ni me aparece el servicio en el listado. ¿Sabes qué se podría hacer en este caso?
Muchas gracias de antemano!